# How do I do iteration in PowerShell and how do I keep intermediate results in an array or list?

Tags: powershell

I am totally new to PowerShell. I just started to pick it up yesterday. When I found a resource called "Learn Windows PowerShell Now Before It's an Emergency", I realized how apt the title is.

PowerShell already offers a very rich set of primitives to search the registry. However, my requirements are a bit more involved. Given a set of GUIDs, I want to locate them all in the registry. Then, based on the registry keys and values, I want to find out their dependencies.

My goal is to provide a drill-down report of the full COM dependencies.

The basics I need to know are:

1. How do I do iteration in PowerShell?
2. How do I keep intermediate results in an array or list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Use [loops](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx).  Standard-style `For`, `Foreach` and `Do/While` are all available.

2) Use [variables](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/variables-arrays-hashes/):

```
$strComputers = @("Server1", "Server2", "Server3")
$strComputers.Count
$strComputers[0]
$strComputers[1]
$strComputers[2]
```

PowerShell doesn't require strongly typed variables, so watch out for magical conversions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this again.

Iteration in powershell is done in one of three ways:

1. Use the foreach command on an array: Foreach ($item in $array) { #actions }
2. Use Powershell select action to build array: $array = Select-childitem -Recurse
3. Send array down the pipe to a filter: $array | where-object{$_ -like "Search String"}

The easiest way to store intimidate results is to add it to an initialized array variable.

```
$array = @() #Initialize array
$array += $item #Add item to array
```

Here is some basic sample code to find something in the registry.

```
cls
$GUID = "*{3336F667-9049-4D46-98B6-4C743EEBC5B1}*"
$RegPath = "HKLM:\"
$Results = Get-ChildItem $RegPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object{$_ -like $GUID}
foreach ($item in $Results)
{
    Write-Host $item
}
```

Using Get-ChildItem is a poor way to search the registry but it does work.

Hope this helps